# Condition visibility on Salesforce flow screen field based on user belonging to a particular public group

Tags: visual-workflow

I am creating a screen flow and want to  set Condition visibility a picklist field based on the user belonging to a particular public group but I can't see option for group.

Comment: This might be little complex as we cannot use groupmember directly. Create a varible of type boolean and query groupmember object with memberid=user.id and get all records and in for loop add a decision and make that variable to True and you can use that variable for visibility

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala - are you sure this works if the Public Group member is a `Role` or `Role w/ Subordinates`? see [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_users.htm)

Comment: @cropredy, Yeah I forgot to mention that point. Yeah it does not work Role or Role w/ Subordinates. It only works if user is added as GroupMember

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly doable in Flow. A public group can have as members

- direct users
- public groups that have direct users
- Roles that have direct users
- Roles and Subordinates which recursively have direct users

See [schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_users.htm)

You will need an element prior to the display of the screen:

- Call an invocable Apex that takes as arguments the userId and groupApiName and returns a boolean (true - in group, false, not in group). This result variable can be used in the filter on the screen flow
- The invocable Apex will need to use the logic shown in this [Help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387341&type=1).